# Html.Action in a shared partial view tying into a shared controller how to route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes, html.actionlink

I have a controller in the shared path

```
 \controller\blah.cs
```

that a partial view is talking to

```
 \views\shared\SomeDir\blah.cshtml
```

All is good except when I try to make a `@Html.Action` link that gets to that shared controller:

```
  @Html.Action("MethodName", new { Area = "Whatever", Controller = "Blah" });
```

works of course but finds the controller in

```
 \Areas\Blah\Controller\Blah.cs
```

which is NOT what I want.

```
  @Html.Action("MethodName", new { Area = "", Controller = "Blah" });
```

does not work either.

```
  @Html.Action("MethodName", new {Controller = "Blah" });
```

does not work either.

Anybody know the right way to get the `@Html.Action` to route to the controller in the root i.e.

```
 \controller\
```

instead of the current area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want this overload of the Html Helper

```
public static MvcHtmlString Action(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues);
```

So using your example, you would have:

```
@Html.Action( "MethodName", "Blah", new { Area = "" });
```

Comment: Yes that worked. Got it answered on another YahooGroup I run as well. 

Thannnnnks!